# How to update a table using an AFTER INSERT trigger in that same table?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have 2 triggers on a table A one is BEFORE INSERT and one AFTER INSERT :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DEMO_TRG
AFTER INSERT
ON A
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
declare
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin

UPDATE A
SET STATUS = 'DONE'
WHERE id_id =:new.p_id;

commit;

END;
/
```

Why the update command in the after insert doesn't work (the status is not set to DONE)? Did I missed something?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? A trigger with `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` and a `commit` doesn't really make sense. What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve? Why don't you just assign a new value to the `status` column in the before trigger? And what does the `before` trigger do?

Comment: Why would you do that in a second trigger on the same transaction? Surely that's a separate statement entirely? Ie. do the insert, then, sometime later, do a separate update statement.?

Comment: A record is inserted in a Web interface ( an existing trigger before insert set its status to 'REQUESTED') I 'm trying to simulate a Web service which update (after a certain time ) the status of this record, this is why i use a trigger after insert and exactly as: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DEMO_TRG AFTER INSERT ON A REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW declare PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; begin dbms_lock.sleep(5) ; UPDATE A SET STATUS = 'DONE' WHERE id_id =:new.p_id; commit; END; / do you have an idea to implement this (using a trigger or other way) .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is due to the `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` - when you do that, you're effectively switching to a different transaction, which won't know about your uncommitted transaction (ie. your insert), so there is nothing for it to update.

What you should do is amend the column (`:new.status := 'DONE'`) in your before trigger. Or, even better, avoid triggers and have the logic in a stored procedure and don't allow anyone to directly insert into the table, although I appreciate this may be a big switch if you have lots of applications inserting directly into tables etc

Comment: The code should wait 5s after the insertion of a record and then update automatically  the status in the table, how can I implement this dynamically?

Comment: I'd have a process that does: insert + commit, wait 5 seconds, update + commit. Probably a sql script that has a call to dbms_lock.sleep to do the waiting.

Comment: i dont have a process which can include insert commit wait 5s and then update..the record is inserted via a web interface and  display at 1st time "REQUESTED" as a status to the interface user and then he should wait 5s to see thi status changed to DONE,this is why i try to use the after insert trigger

Comment: so what is supposed to trigger the status from requested to done? Does another program poll the table and pick up requested rows, do some processing and then mark the row as done? If so, and you're trying to mimic the polling/updating because that section isn't written yet, then I would suggest you create a dbms_scheduler job that polls the table every 5 seconds and picks up any rows that haven't been updated for > 5 seconds. You'd have to have a column that told you when the row was inserted, of course, otherwise you'd have to accept rows could be updated between 0 and 10 seconds after insert

Comment: Thanks for your feedback .At the 1st implemenation I'v already use a job which runs every 2s but as you remarked it the job may take 7s and the specification impose 5s this is why i thought to use a trigger so do you have please any advice.tks